# Theorem classifying fixed point sets of an isometry of the three sphere

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, group-actions

> Let $T:S^3\rightarrow S^3$ be an isometry of finite order. Then the set $S^T=\{x\in S^3|Tx=x\}$ of fixed points is either empty, or a pair of antipodal points, or a great circle, or a great sphere.

Is there a reference for this in some well-known textbook or paper? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Having received a couple of answers containing proofs, I would like to clarify that I know proofs for this and I am specifically looking for a source which can be cited instead of providing a proof (due to space considerations). This question is literally a reference request.

Comment: fixed points of any isometry on a Riemannian manifold must be a totally geodesic submanifold. This is for example given in Kobayashi's _Transformation Groups In Riemannian Geometry_, or as an exercise in O'Neill's _Semi-Riemannian Geometry_. So of the classification you listed, three cases are "general facts" (great circle, great sphere, and empty set). The only $S^3$ specific part about this theorem is the requirement that in the $0$-dimensional case you get a exactly a pair of points and they are antipodes. And that's the case I don't have a reference for.

Comment: Sorry if my question is naive, but isn't this just a direct consequence of the fact that the fixed points in $\mathbb R^4$ are a vector space?

Comment: I think so. But I tend to take reference request questions quite literally.

Comment: Another way to say this: the isometries of the sphere, as a metric space, form the orthogonal group, acting on Euclidean space by linear isometries preserving the origin and hence the sphere. Then the result becomes obvious, since fixed points of linear maps form linear subspaces.

Comment: Fair enough. If I were to use that result I would probably state and prove it in the same sentence, as Ben McKay describes it, but maybe that's cavalier of me. Do we need that $T$ is of finite order? Do you expect that a proof would be easier with this hypothesis, so there might be a reference in this particular case?

Comment: Is citing something really going to be shorter? Ben McKay proved it in three lines, a reference is going to be at least half a line + the bibliographical entry that almost always span at least two lines.